# How to access fragment instance inside a viewPager adapter from a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a process for creating a new restaurant. This is a 5 stage process which I built with a view pager and 5 fragments.

one of the fragments is for the user to upload photos of the place.

My problem starts, when I want to allow users to remove certain photos.

How, from within the recyclerAdapter's instance for that photo, I can remove it from the adapter itself, which is inside a fragment in the viewPager? The viewPager fragments are single instances, and I can't access them, so I'm  a bit lost.

Comment: Do you mean an instance of RecyclerView.Adapter ? When you remove a photo, aren't you on the same fragment containing your RecyclerView.Adapter ?

Comment: Yes. I feel like I'm obviously missing something very basic with the usage of the adapter.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your instance of RecyclerView.Adapter should have a reference to the underlying data it's diplaying e.g. an array or a list of photos in your case.

The underlying data are used inside your Adapter's implementation of `onBindViewHolder()`
to fill the RecyclerView.ViewHolder at the given position.

To remove a photo, your fragment has to remove the corresponding entry in the underlying data set, then refresh the view by calling your adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`